# Site is reported (by some browsers) "not secure" though certificate hasn't expired

Tags: wordpress, apache, google-chrome, ssl, opera

I'm running a Wordpress site on Ubuntu 14.  It's been secure for 23 months.  But with 1 month to go, a few customers' Opera and Chrome browsers are refusing to report the site as secure. SSLLabs.com gives me a grade of A.

I could renew the certificate ... but suspect that wouldn't solve anything b/c this one has NOT expired and NOBODY claims it has.

Ideas?

[image]

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/), [Web Apps Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

New update Google Chrome 56, 57 doesn't trust some CAs, including StartCom https://security.googleblog.com/2016/10/distrusting-wosign-and-startcom.html

You should switch to other CA or use Let's Encrypt.

Comment: Thanks!  That's the answer.  Bugs me ... but ... now I know.

Comment: Note, Let's Encrypt has a serious trust problem, it has issued over 15K certs that include "paypal" in the name. Also Let's Encrypt is not a CA, it uses another CA and issues 2nd level certificates.